# Campo de pesquisa datatable

Tags: html, ajax, mvc, jquery-datatables, datatable

Bom eu sou novo mexendo com datatable, e estou precisando de uma pequena ajuda. Estou com uma dificuldade de adicionar um campo de filtragem por pesquisa de tabela através de uma variável, baseado em valor de uma tabela no banco de dados {Cliente}. Queria saber de alguns métodos (usando o datatable) pra ajudar a filtrar na tabela. (OBS: tentei fazer por PHP só que ele não se conecta na tabela: -[imagem pra ajudar no entendimento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQJkV.png) ).

```
<script>
        $('#zero-config').DataTable({
            "oLanguage": {
                "oPaginate": { "sPrevious": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-left"><line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg>', "sNext": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-right"><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline></svg>' },
                "sInfo": "Exibindo _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "sSearch": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-search"><circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line></svg>',
                "sSearchPlaceholder": "Pesquisar...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Clientes :  _MENU_",
                "processing": false,
                
            },
            "stripeClasses": [],
            "lengthMenu": [0, 10],
            "pageLength": 0,
            
        });

    
    </script>
```